# Using Swagger 2.0, How Can I Show a model that is an array that accepts multiple types?

Tags: swagger, api-design, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm using app.swaggerhub.com to generate a swagger 2.0 spec.

My code looks like this:

```
036  definitions:

---    // code that defines 'fieldRequirement' and 'slideRequirement'

106    requirement:
107      type: array
108      items:
109        oneOf:
110          - $ref: '#/definitions/fieldRequirement'
111          - $ref: '#/definitions/slideRequirement'
```

This returns 3 errors on the same line (106):

```
106 should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: oneOf
106 should be array
106 should match some schema in anyOf
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a model that allows either a fieldRequirement or a slideRequirement as an array element in requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oneOf` is not supported by swagger 2.0, only by [swagger 3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/).

However, you can use polymorphism with field [`discriminator`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-13) if you can't upgrade to swagger 3.0, in your case, you need a file like :

```
requirement:
  type: array
  items:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Requirement'
```

...

```
definitions:
  Requirement:
    type: object
    discriminator: requirementType
    properties:
      requirementType:
        type: string
    required:
    - requirementType
  FieldRequirement:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Requirement'
    - type: object
      properties:
        ...
  SlideRequirement:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Requirement'
    - type: object
      properties:
        ...
```